# LocalStorage doesn't work on PhoneGap

Tags: html, cordova, local-storage, w3c

I create a example of LocalStorage. When I use Chrome web browser, It works fine. But when I test on iPhone Emulator, It doesn't. Please help.
Here is my code to set the local storage value:

```
function onclick(){
    window.localStorage.setItem("data","Nguyen Minh Binh");
}
```

===========

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"    ></script>
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <a data-role="button" href="DemoWOrklightJQM/index.html"  data-prefetch onclick="onclick()">Click me</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code where I tried to get the saved data:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>DemoSimpleControls</title>
            <meta name="viewport"
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
                        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/DemoSimpleControls.css">
                                <script>
                                    window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
                                    </script>
                                <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
                                <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function(){
                                                      $("#mysavedData").html("XYZ");
                                                      $("#mysavedData").html(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
                                                      });

                                </script>
                                </head>

    <body id="content" >
        <div data-role="page" id="page">
            <div data-role="header" >
                <a data-rel="back" href="#" >Back</a>
                <h1>My page</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px" data-theme="e">
                <div id="mysavedData">My data</div>

                        <a href="#" onclick="getData(); return false;" data-role="button" id="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" data-corners="true">Button</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
At Whizkid747's suggest, I change the script source as below but It still doesn't work.

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>DemoSimpleControls</title>
                <meta name="

viewport"
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
                        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/DemoSimpleControls.css">

                                <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
                                <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                                < script  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                                    function onLoad(){
                                        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, false);
                                    }
                                    function deviceready(){
                                        $("#mysavedData").html("XYZ");
                                        $("#mysavedData").html(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
                                    }

                                </script>
                                </head>

    <body id="content" onLoad="onLoad();" >
        <div data-role="page" id="page">
            <div data-role="header" >
                <a data-rel="back" href="#" >Back</a>
                <h1>My page</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px" data-theme="e">
                <div id="mysavedData">My data</div>

                        <a href="#" onclick="getData(); return false;" data-role="button" id="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" data-corners="true">Button</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT2: Try to set localStorage at OnDeviceReady then get it next lines, but still doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact Example</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
            </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/phonegap/phonegap/2.5.0rc1/lib/android/cordova-2.5.0rc1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for PhoneGap to load
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // PhoneGap is ready
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                window.localStorage.setItem("key", "minhbinh");
                var keyname = window.localStorage.key(i);
                // keyname is now equal to "key"
                var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
                // value is now equal to "value"
                window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
                window.localStorage.clear();
                // localStorage is now empty
                $("p#p1").text(value);
            }


            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p id="p1">localStorage</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move your code in document.ready to [onDeviceReady event of PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready). onDeviceReady is when you need to start executing your custom code.

**Edit:** **Try the below code with cordova.js added locally and not from github**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact Example</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
            </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova-2.5.0rc1.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p id="p1">localStorage</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // Wait for PhoneGap to load

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // PhoneGap is ready

            function onDeviceReady() {
                window.localStorage.setItem("key", "minhbinh");
                var keyname = window.localStorage.key(i);
                // keyname is now equal to "key"
                var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
                // value is now equal to "value"
                //window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
                //window.localStorage.clear();
                // localStorage is now empty
                $("p#p1").text(value);
            }


         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I have changed the codes as your suggestion, but It doesn't work.

Comment: I see that you are trying to get data from local storage before setting it. Can you set the data in deviceReady event and then get it in the next line?

Comment: Please see my edit2. I set localstorage at onDeviceReady and get it next line, still doesn't work.

Comment: Please see my edited answer: Try the added code with cordova.js added locally and not from github.

Answer (score 2):

There was a problem when running Cordova 2.1 (fixed in 2.2) on iOS 6: initializing the localstorage the first time the app is run does not work.

Please check this for a solution:
http://www.x-services.nl/cordova-localstorage-cleared-after-first-app-launch-ios6/369