# My code works on the web, but not PhoneGap & jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I got some help here before with a PhoneGap project I had, but the code I got was written on Javascript and didn't work on PhoneGap. I saw that it didn't use the PhoneGap API, so my question is if someone can please help me tell me whats wrong with the code.

Here is the code for my project:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6kM3B/1/

I tried to use the PG API from this code, but still, didn't work.
So if you understand Javascript & PhoneGap & jQuery Mobile, that would be nice if someone could convert or tell me whats wrong with the code.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<title>Last Time I Did It!</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
<link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">            
        <h1>Last time I did it</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
           <li>
              <a data-role="button" href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="add" data-rel="page">ADD</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a data-role="button" href="#page3" data-transition="slide" id="show" data-rel="page">SHOW</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
   <div data-role="header">            
       <h1>Add event</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content">
   <textarea id="newItemText"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div data-role="footer">
      <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
             <li>
                <a data-role="button"  href="#" data-transition="slide" id="btnSave">SAVE</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a data-role="button" href="#page1" id="btnCancel" data-transition="slide"    data-direction="reverse" data-rel="page">CANCEL</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
  <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#page2"  class="ui-btn-left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
    <h1>Events</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="orderedList" data-inset="true">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
     <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>
            <a data-role="button" id="edit">EDIT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-role="button" id="delete">DELETE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page3', function(){ 
//setup the current list

if(localStorage.getItem('TaskList')){
    var TheList = [];
    TheList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TaskList'));
    var items = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < TheList.length; i++) {
        items += '<li><h3>' + TheList[i].text + '</h3><p>' + timeAgo( (new
Date(TheList[i].time).getTime())/1000) + ' ago<p></li>';
    }

    $('#orderedList').empty().append($(items)).listview('refresh');

}

});


$(document).on('pageinit', '#page2', function(){ 

$('#btnCancel').on("click", function(){
    $('#newItemText').val(''); //CLEAR TEXT AREA
});

$('#btnSave').on("click", function(){

    var TheList = [];
    if(localStorage.getItem('TaskList')){
        TheList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TaskList'));
    }
    var newitem = $('#newItemText').val(); 
    var task = {text: newitem, time: new Date() };
    TheList.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem('TaskList', JSON.stringify(TheList));

    $('#newItemText').val(''); //CLEAR TEXT AREA
    $.mobile.navigate( "#page3", { transition : "slide" });

});

});

function timeAgo(time){
var units = [
{ name: "second", limit: 60, in_seconds: 1 },
{ name: "minute", limit: 3600, in_seconds: 60 },
{ name: "hour", limit: 86400, in_seconds: 3600  },
{ name: "day", limit: 604800, in_seconds: 86400 },
{ name: "week", limit: 2629743, in_seconds: 604800  },
{ name: "month", limit: 31556926, in_seconds: 2629743 },
{ name: "year", limit: null, in_seconds: 31556926 }
];
var diff = (new Date() - new Date(time*1000)) / 1000;
if (diff < 5) return "now";

var i = 0;
while (unit = units[i++]) {
if (diff < unit.limit || !unit.limit){
  var diff =  Math.floor(diff / unit.in_seconds);
  return diff + " " + unit.name + (diff>1 ? "s" : "");
}
};
}
```

I also tried to change the whole Javascript code so it works with the PhoneGap API, this is what I done, but still, not working. I read PhoneGap documents, looked at some tutorials and even read a simple Javascript book to understand, but this, this gives me headache.

```
// load function.
function loadList()
        {
    var theList = window.localStorage.getItem('TaskList'));
        var items = '';

        if (null != theList || theList != "null")
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
        items += '<li><h3>' + theList[i].text + '</h3><p>' + timeAgo( (new     Date(theList[i].time).getTime())/1000) + ' ago<p></li>';
            }
        }

    $('#orderedList').empty().append($(items)).listview('refresh');
}

function saveList()
        {
        var listArray = {};
        var textValue = "";

        var list = document.getElementById("orderedList");
        window.localStorage.setItem("TaskList", JSON.stringify(listArray));
        }

function timeAgo(time){
var units = [
{ name: "second", limit: 60, in_seconds: 1 },
{ name: "minute", limit: 3600, in_seconds: 60 },
{ name: "hour", limit: 86400, in_seconds: 3600  },
{ name: "day", limit: 604800, in_seconds: 86400 },
{ name: "week", limit: 2629743, in_seconds: 604800  },
{ name: "month", limit: 31556926, in_seconds: 2629743 },
{ name: "year", limit: null, in_seconds: 31556926 }
];
var diff = (new Date() - new Date(time*1000)) / 1000;
if (diff < 5) return "now";

var i = 0;
while (unit = units[i++]) {
if (diff < unit.limit || !unit.limit){
  var diff =  Math.floor(diff / unit.in_seconds);
  return diff + " " + unit.name + (diff>1 ? "s" : "");
}
};
}
```

Thank you for any helpful answer.

Comment: Not many people here are going to scan through *that* much code. You need to make a stronger effort to narrow down the cause of the problem yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and yes, I do understand that, but from the beginning I get the link to JSFiddler there the first HTML & Javascript is in. The thing is, it works in JSFiddler, you can add and see the counter count, but when you get it over to phonegap and the phone, nothing works.

So, just look at the JSFiddler code, not so much code there, and you can see that it works in JSFiddler. I see that the phonegap API use "window.localstorage" while in my code it is localstorage, but still, after the changes, it will not work.
Will try narrow it down and edit here later :)

Comment: How are you testing? If you add the Cordova lib and test in a browser, does it work? I can't see anything in your code that would prevent it from running with Cordova, so I assume your problems are with the building process or the device/platform specific settings. For android, you can check the log for errors with `adb logcat CordovaLog:D *:S`

Comment: @AJJ Hi. I test the app by go in to CMD, to the folder and write "phonegap run android" and my app will run on the phone, the buttons works, so i can go forward and back, but I cant "save" my text to the listview (orderedList).

In my folder, I find 5 subfolders (.cordova, merges, platforms, plugins & www) in www-folder I put a lib-folder with jquery-mobil.js and jquery.js file. The buildingprocess gets successfully when I run the phonegap run android in cmd... I saw that phonegap API uses "window.localstorage" while i used "localstorage" after changing, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to point out a possible issue in case it helps, although I cannot be sure of whether this is the source of your current problem.

You are calling `localStorage` on `pageinit`, without checking for `deviceready` (I assume, if you posted all your code), and you should wait for that event before using `localStorage` on a device: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage (look out at the bottom of the page for the full example of how to use `localStorage`).

This is the documentation for `ondeviceready`: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready, you already must have a listener defined in `index.js`. So you should move all your `pageinit` listener inside the `ondeviceready` listener.

This related question may help: [LocalStorage doesn't work on PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600432/localstorage-doesnt-work-on-phonegap)

Comment: I sat today and looked att ALL the code and found the problem.
Very retarded problem from my side, so retarded that am embarrassed to even tell here.

THE PROBLEM & THE SOLUTION.
The JSFiddler code is based on jQuery 1.9.1 & jq mobile 1.3.0b1, I was usin jQeery 1.6.4 and mobile 1.1.0, so when I did update this .js files it worked... That WAS the problem, everything else was correct